# Getting ArrayIndexOutOfBounds despite using indexInBounds

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, indexoutofboundsexception, backtracking

Method for checking if and keeping the program inbounds is not working i keep getting: `array IndexOutOfBounds error`. I can't continue to see if my actual implementation of the Knight's Tour works because of this error.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
class KnightsTour {

    static int the_board[][] = new int[8][8];
    int the_tour[][] = new int [8][8];
    int k,moves = 0;
    int x = 0, y = 0; 
    int z, j = 1;
    boolean tour_found, isSafe;

        //fills 2D array with 0's
        public KnightsTour()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
                {
                 for (int r = 0; r < 8; r++) 
                    {
                            the_board[i][r] = 0;
                        }
                }
        }
        /*recursive method, checks how many moves were made if 16 were made tour finished, 
        else if not moves knight checks if the move is valid if not back tracks*/
        public void findTour(int q)
        {
            if(moves == 68)
                {
                    tour_found = true;
                }

            else move(q); 
            if(isSafe == true)
                    {
                        findTour(q++);
                        moves++;
                    }
            else
                if(isSafe == false)
                    {
                        findTour(q*(-1));
                        moves--;
                    }
        }
        //used to keep prevent arrayindexoutofbounds error
        public boolean arrayInBounds(int x, int y)
        { 
        if(x > 8 || y > 8)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            else return true;
        }
        /*move method uses switch statement to decide which move the knight should make
        based on a case number, negative case numbers back track knight. if statement checks
        if the current array element is empty and the index is inbounds*/
        public void move(int a)
        {

            switch (a)
            {
               case 1:
                if(arrayInBounds(x+2, y+1) == true){
                   if(the_board[x+2][y+1] != 0){                          
                        the_board[x+2][y+1]=j;
                            j++;
                        }
                    }
                else isSafe = false;
               case 2:
                if (arrayInBounds(x+1, y+2) == true){
                    if(the_board[x+1][y+2] != 0){               
                            the_board[x+1][y+2]=j;
                            j++;
                        }
                }
                else isSafe = false;
               case 3:
                 if(arrayInBounds(x-1, y+2) == true){
                   if(the_board[x-1][y+2] != 0){           
                            the_board[x-1][y+2]=j;
                            j++;
                        }
                 }
                else isSafe = false;
               case 4:
                if (arrayInBounds(x-2, y+1) == true){
                    if(the_board[x-2][y+1] != 0){           
                            the_board[x-2][y+1]=j;
                            j++;
                        }
                }
                else isSafe = false;
               case 5:
                if(arrayInBounds(x-2, y-1) == true){
                    if(the_board[x-2][y-1] != 0){           
                            the_board[x-2][y-1]=j;
                            j++;
                        }
                }
                else isSafe = false;
               case 6:
                if(arrayInBounds(x-1, y-2) == true){
                        if(the_board[x-1][y-2] != 0){                    
                            the_board[x-1][y-2]=j;
                            j++;
                        }
            }
                else isSafe = false;
               case 7:
                 if(arrayInBounds(x+1, y-2) == true){
                    if(the_board[x+1][y-2] != 0){          
                            the_board[x+1][y-2]=j;
                            j++;
                        }
                 }
                 else isSafe = false;
               case 8:
                if(arrayInBounds(x+2, y-1) == true){
                 if(the_board[x+2][y-1] != 0){
                            the_board[x+2][y-1]=j;
                            j++;
                        }
                }
                else isSafe = false;
               case -1:
                 the_board[x-2][y-1]=0;
                      j--;
               case -2:
                 the_board[x-1][y-2]=0;
                      j--;
               case -3:
                 the_board[x+1][y-2]=0;
                      j--;
               case -4:
                 the_board[x+2][y-1]=0;
                      j--;
              case -5:
                 the_board[x+2][y+1]=0;
                      j--;
               case -6:
                 the_board[x+1][y+2]=0;
                      j--;
               case -7:
                 the_board[x-1][y+2]=0;
                      j--;
               case -8:
                 the_board[x-2][y+1]=0;
                      j--;
                }

        }
        //for loop to display tour once found//         
        public void displayTour()
        {
            int v = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
                {
                 for (int e = 0; e < 8; e++) 
                    {               
                                if(v % 8 == 0)
                                {
                                    System.out.print(the_board[i][e] + "\t");
                                    System.out.println("\n");
                                } 
                        else    
                            System.out.print(the_board[i][e] + "\t");
                            v++;                
                        }
                }

        }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `arrayInBounds` method is incorrect.  `8` is an invalid index, but your method would incorrectly report that as valid.  Also, it doesn't check for invalid indexes below `0`.

Change your method to check if either `x` or `y` is greater than *or equal to* `8`, and also check if either is less than `0`.

Comment: And if I could add a style suggestion, the `if a return false else return true` is a bad anti-pattern. Use `return !a`.

Answer (score 0):

Your board is a two-dimensional array, 8 x 8.  However, because arrays have 0-based indeces, your board really looks like this:

00 10 20 30 40 50 60 70
01 11 21 31 41 51 61 71
02 12 22 32 42 52 62 72
03 13 23 33 43 54 63 73
04 14 24 34 44 54 64 74
05 15 25 35 45 55 65 75
06 16 26 36 46 56 66 76
07 17 27 37 47 57 67 77

Therefore, if you allow indeces with a value of 8, they will actually be in the **9th** position, and thus be out-of-bounds.

So, to see if an array is out of bounds, either check if the index is greater than *or equal to* 8, or check if it is is *greater than 7*.

Or, switch your logic, so that you are checking if it's *in-bounds* rather than if it's *out-of-bounds*.  So I would suggest changing your method:

```
public boolean arrayInBounds(int x, int y) { 
    if(x > 8 || y > 8) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

to this:

```
public boolean arrayInBounds(int x, int y) {
    return (x < 8 && y < 8 && x >= 0 && y >= 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked out!! Now that I got past that problem I am receiving a stack overflow error when I run the program. Any Idea what that might be?

Comment: @user2612136 It sounds like you've got infinite recursion somewhere (a method calling itself without no way of breaking), or possibly an infinite while loop.  Look at what line it's telling you makes the error, in the stack trace.  That should give you an idea of what's doing it.

Comment: @user2612136 Also, it may be that it's being thrown in a different class other than KnightsTour.  You should probably ask about the stack overflow error in a separate question.  (Then link to it in a comment so I can find it and check it out.)  Unless, of course, you solve it yourself (which shouldn't be difficult).